# Normalized superpositions of two, given at will, coherent states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, experimental-technique, coherent-states

In many papers it is nicely demonstrated how to prepare in laboratory an arbitrary pure superposition of  the two  CSS  states $(|z\rangle + |-z\rangle)$  and  $(|z\rangle- |-z\rangle)$ ($z$ arbitrary complex number). This means, in other words, an arbitrary superposition of the two coherent states $|z\rangle$ and $ |-z\rangle$.

I am interested in experimental schemes or realizations of arbitrary, equal-weighted, normalized superpositions of two, given at will, coherent states: $N (|z\rangle + b|x\rangle)$, where $N$ is the normalization factor  and $b$ is  complex numbers of unit modulus.  $x$ and $z$ are the complex amplitudes  of the two coherent components which we choose  practically orthogonal.

I would appreciate very much suggestions of some references, if any, proposing the experimental realization or preparation schemes of pure states of the form $N (|z\rangle + b|x\rangle)$.

Edition. This is the state I have.

For any complex number $\gamma$, let's consider the following normalized equally-weighted linear combinations of two Glauber coherent states $|\gamma\rangle $ and $\left(|\alpha-\gamma\rangle\right) $ :
\begin{eqnarray}|\phi_{\gamma,\pm}(\alpha)\rangle\equiv N_{\gamma,\pm}(\alpha)\left(|\gamma\rangle\pm e^{-i Im(\alpha\gamma^{\star})}|\alpha-\gamma\rangle\right),\quad \alpha\neq 2\gamma,\label{2}\end{eqnarray}
where the normalization constant of these two Schrodinger cat states has the form
\begin{eqnarray}N_{\gamma,\pm}(\alpha)=%1/\sqrt{2\left(1\pm\cos{(2 Im(z\gamma^{\star}))}e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2}}\right)}.
1/\sqrt{2(1\pm e^{-|\alpha-2\gamma|^2/2})}\approx 1/\sqrt{2}\quad \mbox{if}\quad |\alpha-2\gamma|\gg 1.
\label{2_11}\end{eqnarray}

Comment: What does it mean physically to have a *normalized coherent state*? It cannot be a state with a known number of particles...

Comment: @Vadim [Behold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#Mathematical_features_of_the_canonical_coherent_states).

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  Because the overlap of coherent states is Gaussian, you would expect the normalization to be Gaussian as well, and depend on the centroid distance between the cs...

Comment: @CosmasZachos So what does the normalization factor of a coherent state corresponds to? The intensity of a wave?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I suppose the question is not about mathematically normalizing a state (since then it is indeed trivial)

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am not your student. And, even if I were, I would consider such an attitude from a professor as an abuse of power/harassment.

Comment: I found the answer. Thank you.

Comment: p.s. I dont understand why you even started this discussion about normalization, that is correct and can be simply deduced.